# Array containsObject() extension

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm currently using this extension:

```
extension Array
{
    func containsObject(_ object:Any) -> Bool
    {
        if let anObject:AnyObject = object as? AnyObject
        {
            for obj in self
            {
                if let anObj:AnyObject = obj as? AnyObject
                {
                    if anObj === anObject
                    {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I know this is sub-optimal. And it also generates some unnecessary compile-time warnings:

> Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds.
>
> Conditional cast from 'Element' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds.

Can somebody suggest a better extension for checking containment of any kind of object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means there is no need to use conditional cast. Remove the if let and change `as?` to `as`

```
extension Array {
    func containsObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        for obj in self {
            if obj as AnyObject === object as AnyObject {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
extension Array {
    func containsObject(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        return contains(where: {$0 as AnyObject === object as AnyObject})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! The second extension is what I was looking for.